# Create an array [n,[v,..,z]] from a list of key-value pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this input sample:

```
var c1 = "s_A_3";
var c2 = "s_B_10";
var c3 = "s_B_9";
var c4 = "s_C_18";
var c5 = "s_C_19";
var c6 = "s_C_20";
```

Which can easily be concatenated to:

```
var keypairs = ["A_3","B_10","B_9","C_18","C_19","C_20"];
```

And I want to convert this to a multidimensional array like this:

```
var groupArray = [["A",[3]],["B",[10,9]],["C",[18,19,20]]];
```

It's like a kind of card-sorting. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is your expected output when your input is not ordered by letter e.g. `["A_3", "C_20", "B_10", "C_19", "B_9", "C_18"]`?  Is it `[["A", [3]], ["C", [20]], ["B", [10]], ["C", [19]], ["B", [9]], ["C", [18]]]` or `[["A", [3]], ["C", [20, 19, 18]], ["B", [10, 9]]]`?  Or something different entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
function makeGroups(arr) {
    var result = [], prev;
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var x = arr[i].split("_");
        if (prev !== x[0]) {
            prev = x[0];
            result.push([prev, []]);
        }
        result[result.length - 1][1].push(x[1]); // or .push(parseInt(x[1], 10))
    }
    return result;
}

var keypairs = ["A_3","B_10","B_9","C_18","C_19","C_20"];
console.log(makeGroups(keypairs)); 
    // [["A",["3"]],["B",["10","9"]],["C",["18","19","20"]]]
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/mC28n/)

---

The above method assumes the groups will be contiguous (e.g. all `B_` elements appear together). In case your input may be out of order, you can tweak this algorithm to still group all elements together regardless of where they appear in the input:

```
function makeGroups(arr) {
    var result = [], keys = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var x = arr[i].split("_");
        if (!(x[0] in keys)) {
            keys[x[0]] = [];
            result.push([x[0], keys[x[0]]]);
        }
        keys[x[0]].push(x[1]); // or .push(parseInt(x[1], 10))
    }
    return result;
}

var keypairs = ["A_3","B_10","C_18","C_19","C_20","B_9"];
console.log(makeGroups(keypairs));
    // [["A",["3"]],["B",["10","9"]],["C",["18","19","20"]]]
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/mC28n/2/)

Comment: Cool!  Now try it with `["A_3", "C_20", "B_10", "C_19", "B_9", "C_18"]`.  I don't see "sorted letters" in the OP.

Comment: @sqykly I don't see where OP stated that it should be able to handle elements in any order, either. The input sample strongly suggested that the input would be in order, so that is the solution I gave.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to mention "key value pairs" in a JS program, it's usually most appropriate to use... key value pairs =D.

```
function solution(input) {
    var kvp = {},
        result = [];
    input.forEach(function (el) {
        var cut = el.split("_"),
            alpha = cut[0],
            numeric = cut[1],
            elsWithSameAlpha = kvp[alpha] = kvp[alpha] || [];
        elsWithSameAlpha.push(numeric);
    });
    Object.keys(kvp).forEach(function (key) {
        result.push([key, kvp[key]]);
    });
    return result;
}
```